# What is the difference between these sentences?

Tags: tenses

What is the difference between these sentences? I read that all of them can be used in the same situation. So which to choose?

1. When I was young I used to live in a house.
2. When I was young I lived in a house.
3. When I was young I was living in a house.

Comment: Well, all three leave one wondering where else you might have lived.  A cave?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Swan suggests, in WHEN sentences the difference between Past Simple and Past Progressive is the usual use of the latter in narrations. Whereas  in this very case, Past Simple is more preferred, but generally, if the action denote some past habit, then **used to** should be used. *I used to be a good swimmer.*

Comment: And Michael Swan is who?

Comment: He is the author of 'Practical English Usage' and many other necessary for every teacher handbooks.

Comment: I don't have the full context for Swan's assertion, but my guess is the idea of Past Progressive being more likely in WHEN sentences applies specifically in contexts where "simultaneity" (multiple actions/events happening *at the same time*) is a central concept. But in OP's context, ***being young*** and ***living in a house*** are both "long-term" states, so PP isn't necessarily "favoured". And in fact although it wouldn't be "incorrect", I don't think it would be particularly likely in this specific context.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what general rule says. But in the very case above, where we talk about living somewhere, the action which doesn't demand the usage of Progressive. I wrote about Swan's suggestion for this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

"When I was young I used to live in a house" strikes me as a sentence that expresses a deviation from the norm or is indicative of something that makes one stand out from the crowd.

> Many years ago most people lived in cardboard boxes, but when I was
>   young, I **used to live** in a house.

The next one would perhaps be used in a more sequential way:

> When I was young, I **lived** in a house. After I had made my first
>   million, I moved to a castle.

The continuous form strikes me as the start of an exciting story:

> When I was young, I **was living** in a house, and there was this man who
>   one day came up the garden path, frothing at the mouth....

Answer (score 0):

> I used to live in a house.

The phrase "used to" is being used to say the something was true and it is not longer true.

> I used to clean my house, but now I pay someone to do it for me.

The second sentence means that you lived in a house but it does not mean you dont live in a house now.

> When I was young I lived in a house.